# Access denied - Search API from AngelList

Tags: api, swift2, access-token, access-denied

When I'm calling the "search API" from AngelList (https://angel.co/api/spec/search) with the following URL:

`https://api.angel.co/1/search?query=barack&type=Locations&callback=?access_token=707cfhgbdae43060876388ac584bf4cf4fdb`

The result gives me an error: `{"error":"access_denied","error_description":"You must pass in an access token when making this request."}`

I'm not sure why this is happening because when I'm calling other APIs with the same access_token, these run successfully.

How I can solve this situation?

Comment: Hi! I am currently facing the same problem. Did you manage to get past it?

Answer (score 3):

I think you have a typo in your URL. You need an extra **&** character for the **access_token** parameter. And probably you can remove your callback parameter as at this point you can retrieve the data from the response message.

Your URL should be like this:

https://api.angel.co/1/search?query=barack&type=LocationTag&access_token=707cfhgbdae43060876388ac584bf4cf4fdb.

It solved my problem at least :).